# Convert xml tag to anonymous type

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I was looking to convert an xml file I had to
return me a list of anonymous types so I have somethings like this:

```
<Input name="MyProperty" datatype="string">a</Input>
<Input name="SecondProperty" datatype="IPAddress">b</Input>
<Input name="ThirdProperty" datatype="int">c</Input>
```

and wanted it to be converted into a format as below:

```
select new
       {
        MyProperty=a,  
        SecondProperty=b,
        ThridProperty=c,
       }
```

Would it be possible to do this?The idea is to return a list of those inputs to feed into
another method.Also anything wrong doing things this way?

thanks any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the name of the properties, you can do that:

```
XElement doc = ...
var obj = new
{
    MyProperty = doc.Root.Elements("Input").First(e => e.Attribute("name") == "MyProperty").Value,
    SecondProperty = doc.Root.Elements("Input").First(e => e.Attribute("name") == "SecondProperty").Value,
    ThirdProperty = doc.Root.Elements("Input").First(e => e.Attribute("name") == "ThirdProperty").Value
}
```

If you *don't* know the names, you can't use an anonymous type. Anonymous types are really normal types with no name, their members are declared statically.

Comment: I was hoping to generate the name for the anonymous type from the xml attribute name for the name tag...can that work?

Comment: No, because the content of the XML won't be known until runtime. Members of anonymous types have to be known at compile time... Anyway, how would you use the properties of the anonymous type if you don't know their names in advance? A dictionary would probably be more suitable to your needs

Comment: thanks Thomas for your input...but the issue is that I want to load a collection of those inputs at run time and they vary from input to input.I was hoping there was a way to return a list of anonymous types based on the parent input tag.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the solution your looking for but just wanted to through it out there...

Something I've found helpful when faced with XML is decorating a class with the Serializable attribute...it make serializing to and from XML a breeze. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx You can further manipulate the output to get the XML format you need.

Edit to answer you answer your question about varying properties which may not be of interest but here is what could be done:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Input
{
    public List<SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>> PropertyBag { get; set; }
}
```

However, you would not have as much control as all properties will need to be an attribute OR an element represented in XML.

Comment: the thing is I will have a variable list of inputs so I was hoping to create a dynamic type instead of having static entities

Comment: @TommyTwist as long as the structure of the inputs is the same you will be able to serialize an entire list (like List<Input>) with ease.

Comment: @TommyTwist here is a tutorial on the subject in case it interests you. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Comment: thanks for the input but the number of properties may vary so deserializing using the normal means is not feasible...unless there is a way to desealize an xml file without creating a type to serialize to

Comment: @TommyTwist I've edited the answer to add more info...though I am not suggesting that you shoe horn this in if it doesn't fit your needs. Good luck!